# Find optimal combination of items with 2 values

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory, knapsack-problem

I have a list of 500 elements each with 2 values x (float value from 0-Infinity) and a y (float value from 0-1). I need to find the cheapest (lowest sum(x)) combination of 10 of these elements that achieve an average y value less than a given n. I think this is some kind of knapsack problem but I'm unsure of how to fit solutions online to my exact problem and fear that it may be too complicated.

All I have tried so far is trying a solution from ChatGPT but I believe that its complexity is too high. I'm looking for a solution that hopefully can be completed with a high number of elements <1000.

```
def find_cheapest_combination(elements, k, target_avg):
    def backtrack(start, combo):
        if len(combo) == k:
            # Calculate the average float value for the current combination
            avg_float = sum(element[1] for element in combo) / k
            if avg_float <= target_avg:
                nonlocal best_combo, lowest_avg
                best_combo = combo[:]
                lowest_avg = avg_float
            return

        for i in range(start, len(elements)):
            if len(elements) - i < k - len(combo):
                # Not enough elements remaining to form a valid combination
                break
            combo.append(elements[i])
            backtrack(i + 1, combo)
            combo.pop()

    elements.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])  # Sort by price in ascending order
    best_combo = []
    lowest_avg = float('inf')
    backtrack(0, [])

    return best_combo


elements = [(x, y) for x, y in items]
k = 10
target_avg = 0.07
cheapest_combination = find_cheapest_combination(elements, k, target_avg)
print(cheapest_combination)
```

Comment: Any sample inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import milp, LinearConstraint, Bounds

def f(x, y, n, m):
    x, y = np.array(x), np.array(y)
    A = np.vstack([np.ones_like(x), y])
    ub = [n, n * m]
    lb = [n, -np.inf]
    res = milp(x, 
               constraints=LinearConstraint(A, ub=ub, lb=lb), 
               integrality=np.ones_like(x),
               bounds=Bounds(lb=0, ub=1)
              )
    if res.success:
        choices = np.nonzero(res.x)[0]
        return {"choices": choices, 
                "x_sum": res.fun, 
                "y_mean": y[choices].mean()}
```

This function takes as its arguments arrays `x` and `y` of x- and y-values, respectively. `n` is the number of elements to be selected, and `m` is the value that bounds the mean of selected y-values from above. If a solution to the problem exists, the function returns a dictionary of the form

```
{“choices”: indices of selected elements,
 “x_sum”: the sum of x-values of selected elements,
 “y_mean”: the mean of y-values of selected elements}
```

It a solution cannot be found (i.e. no selection of elements gives small enough mean of y-values), the function returns `None`.

For example:

```
f(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[1, 10, 2, 1], n=2, m=2)
```

gives:

```
{'choices': array([0, 2]), 'x_sum': 4.0, 'y_mean': 1.5}
```

**Explanation.** Let `x = [a_1,…,a_k]`, `y=[b_1,…,b_k]`. The problem of selecting some elements of `x` with the smallest sum is equivalent to finding a minimum of the function `a_1*x_1 + … + a_k*x_k` where the value of each variable `x_i` can be either 1 (which means that `a_i` is selected) or 0. The variables `x_i` must satisfy a couple constraints. First, `x_1 + … + x_k = n`, since we want to select exactly `n` elements. Second, `b_1*x_1 + … + b_k*x_k <= n*m`. This condition means that the average of selected `b_i`’s  does not exceed `m`. In this form, the problem becomes an [integer linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). The code uses [`scipy.optimize.milp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html) to compute its solution.

Comment: After implementing this it seems that the output is not adhering to the required items of 10?

```{'choices': array([   5,    7, 1471, 1536, 1746, 1752, 1753, 1763, 1767, 1768, 1770,      1776, 1909, 1917]), 'x_sum': 86.24999999999034, 'y_mean': 0.08847281735922609}```

Comment: Also the sum of x was wrong. Your algorithm gave 86.249 while running through the indexes retroactively gave 122.8. The average y was correct when dividing by 14 instead of 10. Will try on a simpler case to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Interestingly after running the algorithm with slightly differing target means it works and for others it doesn't. Initial run was 0.0902 target which gave 14 choices. 0.09 gave 10. 0.08 and 0.085 both gave 11 choices.

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload my implementation because there very well may be something wrong with it. I will reply if I fix it.

Comment: @caidora If you provide data that gives incorrect results, I will check it.

Answer (score -2):

I don't really see the need for the Dynamic Programming approach to solve this problem.

You can solve this problem with a sliding window technique. The solution goes as follows.

Step 1: Sort the given array by the first element(x)

Step 2: Get the sum of the first 10 x values and y values separately.

Step 3: Check the average value of the sum of y values is less than the target value. If so, you have found the solution.

Step 4: Otherwise, you have slide the window by one element and do the same thing again.

The reason why sorting works in this approach is because you need to find the sum of the 10 x values and minimize the sum. Think of it as selecting the minimum elements to create the sum. For example, if you have a single array [10, 2, 4, 17] and you want to find the minimum sum of 2 elements, you have to select 2 and 4, which are the minimum elements.

Here is a sample code to solve your problem using the sliding window technique:

```
import random

# 500 elements in the list
input_list = [[random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100)] for _ in range(500)]

target_val = 50

# Task: Minimize the sum of 10 elements(x) while keeping sum of corresponding y values less
# less than target_val

# Step 1: Sort the list based on x values
input_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

# Step 2: Take a window of size 10 and find the sum of x values and corresponding y values
window_x_sum = 0
window_y_sum = 0

for i in range(10):
    window_x_sum += input_list[i][0]
    window_y_sum += input_list[i][1]

left_pointer = 0
right_pointer = 10

# Before we start moving the window, we need to check whether the window_y satisfies the condition
# If it does, we have already found the solution
if (window_y_sum / 10) < target_val:
    print("Solution found")
    print("Window: ", input_list[left_pointer:right_pointer])
    print("Window x sum: ", window_x_sum)
    print("Window y sum: ", window_y_sum)
else:
    while right_pointer < 500:
        window_x_sum -= input_list[left_pointer][0]
        window_y_sum -= input_list[left_pointer][1]
        left_pointer += 1
        window_x_sum += input_list[right_pointer][0]
        window_y_sum += input_list[right_pointer][1]
        right_pointer += 1
        if (window_y_sum / 10) < target_val:
            print("Solution found")
            print("Window: ", input_list[left_pointer:right_pointer])
            print("Window x sum: ", window_x_sum)
            print("Window y sum: ", window_y_sum)
            break
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you. I think I was definitely overcomplicating things in my head.

Comment: This will not give the optimal solution in general. There is no reason why the lowest sum that meets the constrain on `y` values should come from consecutive sorted `x`-values.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much but this is better than nothing. Any idea if an optimal solution is possible? Brute force is completely out of the question I believe.

Comment: @bb1 hi, I tried to give a working simple solution. Thank you for reviewing my answer. But I still couldn't get why my solution doesn't give the optimal solution. If you could provide me with a counter example, it would be great for me to learn as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple case that I can think of. 10 items (x=10,y=10) with sum(x)=100. Which achieves the targeted average y of 10. There could exist some x which is greater than all current x values, say x=10.1. But if its y value is 0 this would clearly be a pairing that we would include in our 10 rather than what the algorithm provides.

Comment: @JoelSathiyendra For simplicity assume that we are looking for the smallest sum of just two numbers. Let `x`-values be `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, and the corresponding `y`-values `[0, 100, 0, 0]`. Say that we want the `y`-average at most 1. The sliding window approach will give the sum  `3+4`, but the best solution is `1+3`.

Comment: @bb1 Thank you for the example. Now I understood the question. Thank you! If I can come up with any good answers, I'll post.